# Tomcat: how to share sessionId for all virtual hosts

Tags: session, tomcat, virtualhost

I have a webapp war depoyed in Tomcat8. It can be accessed with different domains that all point to the same IP address.

```
http://a.com
http://b.com
http://c.com
```

Different domains load different contents from the application, and it looks a different app for users.
When a user switches between these domains, how to use the same HTTP session so that users do not need to login again. Usually a new HTTP session will start for a new domain.

Thanks

Comment: you mean something like this? https://bposerow.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/fun-with-cookies-and-tomcat/

Answer (score 1):

Use a Single Sign On System. Don't mess with session cookies that go to different domains. If all of the applications/domains under your control delegate the sign in process to the same machine, the worst you have to do is to click "sign in" and you're signed in. You can even automate this with Javascript. Or require login in every case anyway.

You might want to check CAS, OpenAM (former OpenSSO) or other products for this purpose.